# how to suspend reloadData of tableview being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`reloadData` is `NSLog` out after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`,

I want the tableview call `reloadData` after `GetDataSource` , no `reloadData` on first loading. I even try set  `_tableView.dataSource = nil;` and set it to self in `GetDatasource();`

But `reloadData` keeps being called before `GetDatasource();`
`GetDatasource();` is in `viewDidload()`;

```
  viewWillAppar: <ATOMCutstomNavigationController: 0x1476abfc0>
    viewDidload
     viewWillAppear
    viewWillAppear: <ATOMMyFollowViewController: 0x14751b4c0>
    viewWillLayoutSubviews
    viewDidLayoutSubviews
    reloadData
    viewWillLayoutSubviews
    viewDidLayoutSubviews
    viewDidAppear
    GetDataSource()
```

Anyone has any hint?
How can I suspend reloadData or what mistake I have made ？

> ```
> code In viewDidload:
> ```

```
    _myAttentionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT - NAV_HEIGHT - TAB_HEIGHT)];
    self.view = _myAttentionView;
    _tableView = [[RefreshTableView alloc] initWithFrame:_myAttentionView.bounds];
    [_tableView registerClass:[kfcFollowCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _tableView.estimatedRowHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT - NAV_HEIGHT - TAB_HEIGHT;
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.psDelegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = nil;
    [_myAttentionView addSubview:_tableView];
    _tapMyAttentionGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapMyAttentionGesture:)];
    [_tableView addGestureRecognizer:_tapMyAttentionGesture];
    _canRefreshFooter = YES;
    _dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self firstGetDataSource];


- (void)getDataSource {

    Model *sss = [ATOMShowAttention new];
    [sss Get:param withBlock:^(NSMutableArray *resultArray, NSError *error) {
        if (resultArray.count) {
            [_dataSource removeAllObjects];
        }
        for (ATOMCommonImage *commonImage in resultArray) {
            kfcFollowVM * viewModel = [kfcFollowVM new];
            [viewModel setViewModelData:commonImage];
            [_dataSource addObject:viewModel];
        }
        if (!_hasSetSource) {
            _tableView.dataSource = self;
            _hasSetSource = YES;
        }
        [_tableView reloadData];
        [_tableView.header endRefreshing];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set delegate of tableview = nil when you don't to reloadData?

Comment: can u paste u code in viewDidLoad

Comment: @ShebinKoshy Pasted,sir.

Comment: @PeiweiChen  firstGetDataSource method. what is that? are you collecting datas to array? or doing anything with tableView?

Comment: @ShebinKoshy GetDataSource = firstGetDataSource , fetch data from server and set it to array which is datasource. I paste the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

in view did load

```
_myAttentionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT - NAV_HEIGHT - TAB_HEIGHT)];
self.view = _myAttentionView;
_tableView = [[RefreshTableView alloc] initWithFrame:_myAttentionView.bounds];
_dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];//do it HERE..........
[self firstGetDataSource];//do it HERE...........
[_tableView registerClass:[kfcFollowCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT - NAV_HEIGHT - TAB_HEIGHT;
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.psDelegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = nil;
[_myAttentionView addSubview:_tableView];
_tapMyAttentionGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapMyAttentionGesture:)];
[_tableView addGestureRecognizer:_tapMyAttentionGesture];
_canRefreshFooter = YES;
```